# SQL Server Error : String or binary data would be truncated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

My table :

```
log_id                 bigint
old_value                  xml
new_value                  xml
module                 varchar(50)
reference_id           bigint
[transaction]          varchar(100)
transaction_status         varchar(10)
stack_trace                ntext
modified_on                datetime
modified_by                bigint
```

Insert Query :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[audit_log]
           ([old_value],[new_value],[module],[reference_id],[transaction]
           ,[transaction_status],[stack_trace],[modified_on],[modified_by])
     VALUES
            ('asdf','asdf','Subscriber',4,'_transaction',
            '_transaction_status','_stack_trace',getdate(),555)
```

Error :

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 14, Line 1
String or binary data would be truncated.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Why is that ???

Comment: +1 for providing sufficient information to understand your question. I almost took it back for not reading the error message and looking at your SQL to catch it yourself, though. :-)

Comment: Just a suggestion  : If you are not sure about the length of the  values in Transaction_status make it to varchar(max)

Comment: @praveen wow, that is not a very good suggestion at all. You don't know that they don't know how long the column will be, and the first response is to find out. Should I buy a 30-bedroom house in case I have 30 kids? Of course not.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You're trying to write more data than a specific column can store.  Check the sizes of the data you're trying to insert against the sizes of each of the fields.

In this case transaction_status is a varchar(10) and you're trying to store 19 characters to it.

Comment: Why does not *MSSQL* list the columns that are too short? Is it possible to obtain that list?

Answer (score 3):

this type of error generally occurs when you have to put characters or values more than that you have specified in Database table like in this case:
you specify
  `transaction_status         varchar(10)` 
but you actually trying to store
 `_transaction_status`
 which contain 19 characters. 
that's why you faced this type of  error in this code..

Answer (score 3):

This error is usually encountered when inserting a record in a table where one of the columns is a VARCHAR or CHAR data type and the length of the value being inserted is longer than the length of the column.

I am not satisfied how Microsoft decided to inform with this "dry" response message, without any point of where to look for the answer.

Comment: With SQL Server 2019 the error is more descriptive with the actual real line number and the data that would be truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:-
Alter Column size:
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[audit_log] ALTER COLUMN transaction_status varchar(20)
GO

Solution 2:-
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

Solution 3:-
if don't want to modify the length then ok to trunct value then use
LEFT('text',10)