# How to fix "String or binary data would be truncated" when convert .docx file to binary and insert into varbinary(Max)?

Tags: c#, sql-server, byte

I Use FileStream to Insert file into column with Varbinaray(Max).
This is my sample code :

```
byte[] dataBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(fileNameAndPath);
string insertCommand = string.Format(@" INSERT INTO [dbo].[ts000Attachments] ([Data]) values   (@Data)");
command.Parameters.Add("@Data",SqlDbType.VarBinary,-1).Value = dataBytes;

command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

above code work with .doc file.
How to fix this Problem.

Comment: This column is probably not a varbinary(max). Prove that it is.

Comment: This error will occur only if column size is lesser than the data which you try to insert into that column. Make sure column with a size of max.

Comment: I Create Table With below statement :
CREATE TABLE [ts000Attachments] (
[Id]   uniqueidentifier ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL DEFAULT (NEWID()) PRIMARY KEY,
[Data] varbinary(max)   FILESTREAM NOT NULL,
)
GO
but is not work and throw exception

Comment: Replace `dataBytes` by `new byte[1]` and see if the error goes away. If not, what exact exception including stack do you get?

Comment: Only When I Want to insert .docx file see this exception but when i insert the same file with .doc format it is correctly work.
For Example : I have a file with name 'test.doc' and this file contain 'hi. Mr.' and when i use above code it is correctly inserted. but when save as the same file by .docx postfix i see above exception.
Message Of Exception is : "String or binary data would be truncated.\r\nThe statement has been terminated"

Comment: Perform the test that I requested. Do not just ignore comments.

Comment: And My File is not greater than 1MB.

Comment: When i changed databytes to new byte[1] again see "String or binary data would be truncated..." , why?

Comment: I asked you to provide certain information. Follow up on everything that has been said.

Comment: Thank you all.
My Problem Was Solved.
I Save File Name And File Data. I had an error in the file name. my file name in table was nvarchar 50 but selected file length was 51.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to below links, this issue is all about column size in sql:

StackOverflow:

[SQL Server String or binary data would be truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6388756/sql-server-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated)

[SQL Server Error : String or binary data would be truncated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10843567/sql-server-error-string-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated/17783839)

Microsoft:

[String or binary data would be truncated" and field specifications](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/ec184168-ddd1-4df5-b2c7-c6671b602a3d/quotstring-or-binary-data-would-be-truncatedquot-and-field-specifications?forum=transactsql)

CodeProject:

[String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/697283/String-or-binary-data-would-be-truncated-The-state)

also make sure that FileStream feature is activated on your table.
for me I don't know why my table did not create with FileStream Feature. so, I dropped the table and re-create it.